# Has there been any research addressing systemic racism targeting West Indian immigrants relative to other ethnic immigrant groups?

Tags: united-states, immigration, racism

In a 2018 Quilette opinion column, Coleman Hughes used similar data to suggest systemic racism in the US is not a large problem:

> The second natural experiment involves comparing the outcomes of black immigrants on the whole with the outcomes of American blacks (i.e., blacks descended from American slaves.) Although black immigrants (and especially their children, who are indistinguishable from American blacks) presumably experience the same ongoing systemic biases that black descendants of American slaves do, nearly all black immigrant groups out-earn American blacks, and many—including Ghanaians, Nigerians, Barbadians, and Trinidadians & Tobagonians—out-earn the national average.

Suzanne Model argues in a 2008 book that this only compares the incomes of West Indian immigrants to native black Americans, which can also be explained by selection bias of immigrants.

The Center for Immigration studies published a report titled "Immigrants in the United States" in 2010. Table 10 shows that Jamaican and Haitian immigrants, and their children, are less likely to be in poverty than native-born Black Americans and those from countries with similar GDPs (e.g. Guatamala versus Haiti, Equador or Laos versus Jamaica).

Has there been any other published research addressing the comparison between outcomes of West Indian immigrants vs. that of other immigrant communities like this data from the Center for Immigration studies?

Comment: Maybe that title needs tweaking? Maybe you want to say something like "systemic racism *targeting* immigrants" etc. Also, the folks who down-voted would be polite to explain why they did it. I have not voted as yet.

Comment: @puppetsock I edited it. I posted a broader question using the same description in Skeptics SE, and it was closed for being too broad. I looked and do not think there have been any studies making this specific comparison, so I will not be surprised if this is not answered, but I wanted to check.

Comment: Would like to note: that data may prove that immigrants from those countries are particularly hardworking/talented/insert-positive-adjective here, but the racism argument is a non sequitur: just because people can succeed *in spite of racism* doesn't mean that racism isn't a problem.

Comment: @JaredSmith Technically true, but it would still be an important data point when assessing the degree of racism present. These are large bodies of people.